Is it possible to have to subqueries inside a coalesce?
I want to do something like this inside a stored procedure:
WHERE
  transaction_timestamp::DATE IN 
  (COALESCE(
    (SELECT DISTINCT trx_date FROM query_1), 
    (SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN date_1::DATE IS NOT NULL THEN date_1::DATE ELSE date_2::DATE END AS trx_date FROM query_2)
    )
  )

It's giving me:

Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

query_1 table it's a CTE subquery created before, so could response a null value because that table has no records, so in that case, i would like to filter transaction_timestamp::DATE of the main table from the second query_2 table. And yes, in both cases, the dates could be more than one thats why i use the 'IN'

COALESCE Function expects 2 or more arguments, but these arguments must be singular values.
You can either use MAX, MIN or LIMIT 1 to make sure to return a single value.
If this is doesn't work for you, the other alternative could be using CASE

ohhh great, i can use two coalesces, one filtering max date using <= COALESCE(SELECT MAX .. FROM ..), (SELECT MAX.. FROM ..)) AND other condition with >= COALESCE(SELECT MIN .. FROM ..), (SELECT MIN.. FROM ..)). Thanks!
